# How to extract single file from tar.gz archive using node js

Tags: node.js, archive, extract

```
var targz = require('tar.gz');
var extract = new targz().extract(targzFile , destnDir, function(err){
if(err)
     console.log(err);
console.log('The extraction has ended :'+counter);
});
```

The above code extracts targzFile to destnDir, however I would want to extract single file from targzFile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have that option looking at the [source for node-tar.gz](https://github.com/cranic/node-tar.gz/blob/master/src/targz.coffee). See the code starting on line 68 to see what is going on with `.extract`.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone interested in the answer, it is possible using streams and the module [tar-stream](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream). Here is a complete example that extracts a file called *documents.json* from the archive *archive.tar.gz*:

```
var tar = require('tar-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var extract = tar.extract();
var data = '';

extract.on('entry', function(header, stream, cb) {
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    if (header.name == 'documents.json')
        data += chunk;
    });

    stream.on('end', function() {
        cb();
    });

    stream.resume();
});

extract.on('finish', function() {
    fs.writeFile('documents.json', data);
});

fs.createReadStream('archive.tar.gz')
    .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
    .pipe(extract);
```

Comment: Check that the entry is a file before reading it: `header.type === 'file'`

Comment: You can skip reading the files that you don't need. Type at the start of the `entry` callback: `if (header.name !== 'document.json') { stream.resume(); sb() }` and remove the name check from the `data` callback.

Comment: File reading errors should be handled. Add this before `stream.resume()`: `stream.on('error', cb)`

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but Gianni's solution didn't quite work for me, maybe because he was extracting text files, I'm not sure.

Also, you can optimize quite a bit by only checking the header name once instead of for every data chunk for every file record.

```
var tar = require('tar-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var extract = tar.extract();
var chunks = [];

extract.on('entry', function(header, stream, next) {
    if (header.name == 'documents.bin') {
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
    }

    stream.on('end', function() {
        next();
    });

    stream.resume();
});

extract.on('finish', function() {
    if (chunks.length) {
        var data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        fs.writeFile('documents.bin', data);
    }
});

fs.createReadStream('archive.tar.gz')
    .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
    .pipe(extract);
```

Answer (score -3):

This simple snippet is working for me, and unzips `zipped.tgz` into `downloaded.json` :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const os = fs.createWriteStream('downloaded.json');
fs.createReadStream('zipped.tgz')
        .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
        .pipe(os);
```

Comment: That snipped assumes the `downloaded.json` file to be gzipped (not tarred) and then wrongfully renamed to zipped.tgz. A .tar.gz isn't called tar and gz for no reason. First, the archive is built just concatenating files with some metadata. That produces a .tar file. Then the file is compressed as a single file. All the tarred files are treated as a single file and compressed which adds the .gz extension.