# Node.js How to unzip .csv file which is in folder which is in .tgz archive

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, archive, unzip

I have an archive - "list_users.tgz" and inside it there is a folder "out" and inside this folder is the "list_users.csv" file that I want to unzip and use.

For the reading of the .csv file - I have code:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('/home/some_project/list_users.csv', 'utf8');
const records = parse(data, {columns: true});
```

But how to generate the .csv file from the archive before that?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32916564/830067

Comment: oyophant, not exactly because the code in this link is for stream, but I wanted to unzip a local file.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as that:

```
await tar.x({file: fileDir});
```

Helpful link with more scenarios - https://gist.github.com/noyobo/b0ed1722a59302cfc99c2ec93be6807c

The entire code:

```
const tar = require('tar');
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('csv-parse/sync').parse;

async function getUsers() {
    fileDir = '/mnt/out/list_users.tgz';
    await tar.x({file: fileDir});
    const data = fs.readFileSync('<directory where your app.js file is>', 'utf8');
    const records = parse(data, {columns: true});
    return records;
```